# Почему отрабатывает конструктор класса в отсутствие создания экземпляров java?

Tags: java, конструктор, singleton

Доброго времени суток коллеги! 
У меня есть очень простой код:

```
public class Singleton {
      static Singleton st = new Singleton();
    Singleton(){
        System.out.println("Инициализация ");

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

Класс содержит одно поле - самого себя. Точка входа - пустая, в мэйне ничего не создаётся. Тем не менее конструктор отрабатывает, в консоль выводит:

`Инициализация`

**Вопрос:** Почему отрабатывает конструктор и где про это можно прочитать?

Comment: в [jls](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2)

Comment: Это называется статическая инициализация. При загрузке класса все статические поля инициализируются и статические блоки исполняются. У тебя поле `static Singleton st` является статическим, поэтому при загрузке класса выполняется инициализация этого поля значением `new Singleton();`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Статические поля/блоки инициализируются при первом обращении к классу, т.к. у вас в **Singleton** находится точка входа в программу, метод `public static void main(String[] args)`, то тогда и происходит первое обращение.

Таким образом, запуская программу через main вы начинаете загрузку класса. В первую очередь загружается статическое поле

`static Singleton st = new Singleton()`.

Оператор new вызывает конструктор класса.

Порядок и правила инициализации хорошо освещены в "Философия Java"  Брюс Эккель

Comment: Если быть точным статические блоки/поля инициализируются при первой загрузке класса

Comment: Дополню: он может сделать так: private Singleton st = new Singleton(); + get&setSinglton (в данном случае наверно только get?)

Comment: @Barmaley а что означает "первая загрузка класса". Если я точку входа в классе написал, это будет первая загрузка или как-то по другому?

Comment: Загрузка означает, загрузку образа класса в JVM - как правило ClassLoader'ом

Comment: @Barmaley а в моём примере, образ класса попал в JVM из-за наличия main?

Comment: @AndrewKachalin, да, т.к. при старте приложения вызывается метод main в вашем классе, т.е. происходит его первая загрузка, попробуйте создать отдельный класс без метода main, с аналогичным статическим полем и запустить